# Add unread/notifcation count to PagerSlidingTabStrip

Tags: android, spannablestring, pagerslidingtabstrip

I've been trying to add custom view on `PagerSlidingTabStrip` which can be used as unread counter or notification count for that page. I am using PagerSlidingTabStrip as it iss more customisable than SlidingTabLayout.

[image: unread counter]

I have tried the following:-

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
  SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    String mCounterText = "1";
    String mHeaderText = "Header ";
    stringBuilder.append(mHeaderText);
    stringBuilder.append(mCounterText);
    stringBuilder.setSpan(new RoundedBackgroundSpan(), mHeaderText.length()-1, mHeaderText.length()+mCounterText.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
   return stringBuilder;
}
```

I also tried to pass Html from `getPageTitle` but still it extracts only string out of it. Styling is not applicable to Title Of Tabs.

*No matter what I passed from `getPageTitle`, it just extracts simple string out of it.*

Following is what I've achieved so far:

[image]

I've tried with `SlidingTabLayout` which do gimme result of unread/notification counter but it works with 2.3.7 and not with any version above then.
[image: 2.3.7]

*Why it didn't work with version above 2.3.7?*

RoundedBackgroundSpan :-

```
public class RoundedBackgroundSpan extends ReplacementSpan {
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.text.style.ReplacementSpan#draw(android.graphics.Canvas,
     * java.lang.CharSequence, int, int, float, int, int, int,
     * android.graphics.Paint)
     */
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end,
            float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RectF rect = new RectF(x, top,
                x + MeasureText(paint, text, start, end), bottom);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));//background color
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, 3, 3, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));//text color
        canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x, y, paint);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.text.style.ReplacementSpan#getSize(android.graphics.Paint,
     * java.lang.CharSequence, int, int, android.graphics.Paint.FontMetricsInt)
     */
    @Override
    public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end,
            FontMetricsInt fm) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Math.round(MeasureText(paint, text, start, end));
    }

    private float MeasureText(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start,
            int end) {
        return paint.measureText(text, start, end);
    }

}
```

[image: Screenshot of 5.0]

Comment: Looks like a custom implementation of `ReplacementSpan`.

Comment: @Vikram : Tried with ReplacementSpan but still it extracts only string out of it.

Comment: This is a guess.. I have seen `all caps` interfere with spans before. Do you set this in your text styles?

Comment: I have no idea about this, but I do know that you should not include the space in your header text, because the centering will be slightly off when there is no notification. Only add the space if there is a notification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've slightly tweaked `SlidingTabLayout`. Here's what I did :-

```
protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

       /* if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // If we're running on Honeycomb or newer, then we can use the Theme's
            // selectableItemBackground to ensure that the View has a pressed state
            TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
            getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                    outValue, true);
            textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            // If we're running on ICS or newer, enable all-caps to match the Action Bar tab style
            textView.setAllCaps(true);
        }*/

        int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

        return textView;
    }
```

[image: SlidingTabLayout with Counter]

Answer (score 0):

I did it by custom view.
Edit PagerSlidingTabStrip.java file like below.

```
private void addIconTab(final int position, int resId) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_tab, null);
    ImageButton tab = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.img_icon);
    tab.setImageResource(resId);
    addTab(position, view);
}
```

If you use text tab, modify addTextTab() method.

Add method to change count.

```
public void setIndicatorCount(int index, String count) {
    RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout)tabsContainer.getChildAt(index);
    View tv = view.getChildAt(1);
    if(tv instanceof TextView) {
        ((TextView) tv).setText(count);
    }
}
```

Call it in your activity or fragment to set count.

And layout.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/img_icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_number"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```